# Entities updated but not saved after SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three EF entities (A;B;C) where B and C inherrit from A.

A has a bool property (boolBitflag).

My problem is the following.

I make changes to an instance of B, attach it to a new objectContext, change the entityState to changed, save the changes, and they are saved.

When I make changes to B and the parrentclass instance of A, I attach the entity to a new object context, change the entitystate, save the changes, ... The following happens.
The Changes in B are saved, but the changes in the A parrent is not being updated. In debugging time everything looks perectly fine. Savechanges triggers no exception, yet the changes are not saved in the parrent entity.

**EDIT**
I simplified it a little bit.

```
B bInstance;

using(var con = new DbContext())
{
    bInstance = con.A.OfType<B>().ToList().FirstOrDefault(); 
    // bInstance.Name = "ExampleText"
    // bInstance.boolBitflag = False
}

using(var con = new DbContext())
{
    bInstance.Name = "Example" //Property of B
    bInstance.boolBitflag = True //Property of A

    con.A.Attach(bInstance);
    ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(bInstance, EntityState.Modified);
    con.SaveChanges();
}

//
    // bInstance.Name = "Example"
    // bInstance.boolBitflag = False
```

Comment: Please show your code so that we can help.

Comment: If B inherits from A, there is no distinction between an instance of B and "the parentclass instance of A" - B *is* an instance of A

Comment: code? Errrrrr. thats kind of a problem. Too much stuff.

Comment: Nothing WPF specific here, removing tag.